# How to adjust dimensions in numpy.array

Tags: python, numpy

all

I have a numpy array, the dimension of the element is different. for example:

```
[
 [1,2,3],
 [2,3,4,5,6]
 [1,2]
]
```

I want to adjust the element dimension, set the dimension as the largest one, and fill with 0, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a placeholder with the desired shape first, then fill the placeholder with the `data` list

```
data = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4,5,6], [1,2]]

# create a placeholder
tmp = np.zeros((len(data), max([len(item) for item in data])))

# fill the placeholder with data
for ind, line in enumerate(data):
    tmp[ind, :len(line)] = line
```

However, this may not be super fast when the size of the data list is large.

Comment: Can you please add some explanation so that it would help for others to undestand